# Coroutine launched without specifying a dispatcher is not getting cancelled

Tags: kotlin-coroutines

I created a coroutine with just one computation loop with the exit condition of isActive. It cancels correctly when I specify the default dispatcher, but does not cancel when no dispatcher is defined.

```
//This example cancels as expected
 fun main() = runBlocking {
        val job = launch(Dispatchers.Default) {
        println("Start job 1")
        var i =0
        while (isActive){
            print(i++)
            print(i--)
        }

        println("End job 1")
    }

     job.cancelAndJoin() 
 }
```

However, the below example does not cancel and keeps executing the loop.

```
 fun main() = runBlocking {
    val job = launch {
    println("Start job 2")
    var i =0
    while (isActive){
        print(i++)
        print(i--)
    }

    println("End job 2")
    }
    job.cancelAndJoin()
}
```

Why is the second example behaving differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `runBlocking`, if you don't specify a dispatcher, coroutines will be dispatched directly on the current thread, using an event loop. Because there's only a single thread in use, the coroutines can't run in parallel. Once the loop is started, it runs continuously, occupying the thread. That means that the call to `cancelAndJoin` can never be reached, even though it's in a separate coroutine, because there's no thread available to continue running that coroutine.

When you use the default dispatcher, you're introducing more threads. The default dispatcher has a pool of threads, meaning that coroutines can run in parallel. That means that the code can continue and reach the call to `cancelAndJoin` even when the loop is still running.